# Flex Box Responsive Layout

Tags: html, css, flexbox, responsive

I'am working on flex-box responsive project for school. But I have problems with it. First time I did it, the code was complete mess and couldn't make it responsive. Can someone help me with this layout ? I have been smashing my head for like 6 hours now this is the layout I need to do. It has to be flexbox and responsive:

[image]

Comment: Hi and Welcome to SO. Please post your attempt as a minimal reproduciable code snippet (ctrl + m) and tell us where you got stuck. SO is no plattform where users will code for you. It is for specific coding issues only. Means we help to debug but not to write the entire code for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```html
    <div style="display:flex; flex-direction:column; ">
       <header>header</header>
       <main style="display:flex;flex-direction:row;">
         <div style="width:70%; height:auto;">article1</div>
         <div style="width:30%;height:auto; display:flex; flex-direction:column;">
             <div>menu</div>
            <div>article2</div>
         </div>
      </main>
       <footer>footer</footer>


   </div>
```

Comment: Hi and Welcome to SO. Please always give a sufficient explanation of your solution to be reproduciable. Anwsers with unexplained code lines are considered low quality.

Answer (score 0):

header and footer don't need to be flex.

try:

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
}

.article1 {
  flex: 2;
}

aside {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="article1"></div>
  <aside>
    <div class="menu"></div>
    <div class="article2"></div>
  </aside>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi and Welcome to SO. Please always give a sufficient explanation of your solution to be reproduciable. Also post your code as a snippet (ctrl + m)  and make it visually complete to show that your solution works. Anwsers with `try this... + unexplained code lines` are considered low quality.